# Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am new in ASP .NET MVC. I try to use Entity Framework, but it falls because it does not found EF. I search a solution and in another post says that I have to change the version. I did, but it was unsuccessfull.

Web.config:

```
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-SportsStore.WebUI-20150201211232;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-SportsStore.WebUI-20150201211232.mdf" />-->
    <!--<add name="EFDbContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(localDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=SportsStore;Integrated Security=True" />-->
    <add name="EFDbContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-SportsStore.WebUI-20150201211232;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-SportsStore.WebUI-20150201211232.mdf" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

That is error from the browser.

Server Error in '/' Application.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error: 


Line 11:     public class EFProductRepository : IProductsRepository
Line 12:     {
Line 13:         private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();
Line 14: 
Line 15:         public IQueryable<Product> Products {

Source File: c:\Users\ruben\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SportsStore\SportsStore.Domain\Concrete\EFProductRepository.cs    Line: 13 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' could not be loaded.


=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = rubenPC\ruben
LOG: DisplayName = EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/ruben/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/SportsStore/SportsStore.WebUI/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\ruben\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SportsStore\SportsStore.WebUI\bin
Calling assembly : SportsStore.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\ruben\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SportsStore\SportsStore.WebUI\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\ruben\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/ruben/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/400ee849/decd1b79/EntityFramework.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/ruben/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/400ee849/decd1b79/EntityFramework/EntityFramework.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/ruben/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/SportsStore/SportsStore.WebUI/bin/EntityFramework.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

Stack Trace: 


[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   SportsStore.Domain.Concrete.EFProductRepository..ctor() in c:\Users\ruben\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SportsStore\SportsStore.Domain\Concrete\EFProductRepository.cs:13
   DynamicInjectorf437813e479848489e7ebb4769e5ef53(Object[] ) +70
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context) +884
   Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object scope) +218
   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() +277
   Ninject.<>c__DisplayClass15.<Resolve>b__f(IBinding binding) +86
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +145
   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +4078797
   Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type service, IContext parent) +169
   Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent) +747
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext context, ITarget target) +269
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Create>b__2(ITarget target) +69
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +66
   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +216
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +77
   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context) +847
   Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object scope) +218
   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() +277
   Ninject.<>c__DisplayClass15.<Resolve>b__f(IBinding binding) +86
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +145
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +191
   Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get(IResolutionRoot root, Type service, IParameter[] parameters) +70
   SportsStore.WebUI.Infrastructure.NinjectControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) in c:\Users\ruben\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SportsStore\SportsStore.WebUI\Infrastructure\NinjectControllerFactory.cs:27
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +74
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +197
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237
```

And that is the code where break:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SportsStore.Domain.Abstract;
using SportsStore.Domain.Entities;

namespace SportsStore.Domain.Concrete
{
    public class EFProductRepository : IProductsRepository
    {
        private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

        public IQueryable<Product> Products {
            get { return context.Products; }
        }
    }
}
```

The class EFDbContext.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SportsStore.Domain.Entities;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace SportsStore.Domain.Concrete
{
    public class EFDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Open  Toos>Nuget Package Manager>Package Manager Console then run install-package entityframework -version 6.0.0.0

Comment: Entity Framework is not a part of MVC, you have to install it separately if you are not using a template that already includes it.  You do this through the nuget package manager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Open**

```
Toos > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Console
```

**then run**

```
install-package entityframework -version 6.0.0.0
```

Comment: It works fine on my machine but throwing error on hosted server